# После слова «понимаю» нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

*Я в свою очередь понимаю какие отношения хочу с тобой и то, что ты можешь дать мне всё.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, придаточное, перед которым вы хотите поставить запятую, надо обособить с **обеих** сторон, во-вторых, надо бы поменять *падеж,* а в-третьих, я бы слегка перестроил предложение:

> *Я в свою очередь понимаю, как**их** отношен**ий** хочу с тобой, а также понимаю, что ты можешь дать мне всё.*