Нужна ли запятая после "хочу"? Тут объединяющая главная часть "Я понимаю"
Я понимаю, чего хочу(?) и то, что ты готов мне это дать.
Т.е. я понимаю и чего хочу, и тот факт, что ты готов мне это дать.

Правильно:
Я понимаю, (1) чего хочу и (2) то, что ты готов мне это дать.
Сравнить: Я понимаю, чего хочу и что ты готов мне это дать.
Пояснение
Это СПП  с двумя изъяснительными однородными придаточными, поэтому запятая перед союзом И не ставится.
Но предложение построено особым образом: здесь однородная грамматическая связь между первым придаточным и указательным словом ТО.
Сами придаточные имеют неодинаковую структуру. В первом придаточном союзное слово ЧЕГО в роли дополнения, а во втором придаточном указательное слово ТО и союз ЧТО (дополнением является местоимение это).
Тем не менее эти придаточные однородны, так как отнесены к одному сказуемому понимаю в главном предложении.

Спасибо! Встретила это предложение на форуме https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460120/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f Тут ведь тоже не нужна запятая перед И, правда?

Да, не нужна: Я в свою очередь понимаю, какие отношения хочу с тобой и то, что ты можешь дать мне всё.

Вот!) Там просто ответчик так безапелляционно заявил: придаточное, перед которым вы хотите поставить запятую, надо обособить с обеих сторон. :=/

Это да, но интересно то, что он предложил использовать союз А ТАКЖЕ Почему? Предложение распространенное, произносительная пауза ясно ощущается, а это повод для того, чтобы считать союз И присоединительным. Но тогда это скорее авторская пунктуация, уж лучше взять А ТАКЖЕ,  Грамматика сложная, объяснить непросто  и т.д. В вашем предложении нет таких проблем ввиду небольшой распространенности.  Там же лучше написать так: Я в свою очередь понимаю, какие отношения хочу с тобой и  что ты можешь дать мне всё.  В вашем случае такая запись тоже возможна.

Я понимаю причину осложнения конструкции указательным местоимением: в первом предложении союзное слово ЧЕГО, а во втором союз ЧТО, Н такая разница в грамматике не сказывается на однородности изъяснительных придаточных.  Поэтому лучше не использовать местоимение ТО.

Я понимаю, что с ТО коряво и там и там. Тот ответчик хороший вариант предложил с "а также". Просто не поняла, зачем в первоначальном обособлять придаточное) Спасибо за ответы!
